# how to use 'a significant' to modify a number?

Tags: phrase-usage

In the quote below, 'a significant' is used to modify 15%.

> **A significant** 15% of people said they trust none of these sectors with
> their data.  (The Guardian)

I wonder if I can use 'a significant' to modify a number that isn't a percentage? I want to say that 100 million people said they trust none of these sectors with their date and '100 million' is a significant number.

> **A significant** 100 million people said they trust none of these sectors with
> their data.  (My version)

Or do I **have to** make it more precise like:

> **A significant number of** 100 million people said they trust none of these sectors with
> their data.  (My version)

Comment: The final example looks like you're talking about a fraction of the 100 million people, not 100 million people. But do you actually know what "significant" means? What do you want to say? Did you really ask more than 100 million people who they trusted, because if not, then that's incorrect. A Stack Exchange question is supposed to be about a real problem you face.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my question to make it more clear. Does "a significant 100 million people" work?

Comment: 100 million could hardly be called an insignificant number! (So there is no reason to describe it as 'significant'.) I think the point of the sentence from the _Guardian_ is that 15%, even though quite a small percentage, is significant in that context.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for the insight. Let's say 5 million. My point is whether it is alright to use an adjective to modify a number that is not a percentage, like **a significant 5 million** people said...

Comment: If it was a really enormous survey and 5,000,000 was only a small proportion of the people surveyed, there's no grammatical reason why you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks again. Grammatically speaking, does 'a significant' function like 'an estimated', like 'an estimated 5 million people'. I have trouble understanding the combination of 'a' and 'million people'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying: 'Context is All'

Subject's context: If the document gives enough context to confirm the number's significance then just say '100 million' (If the context is talking about a total population'). Saying 'a significant 100 million' is fine if extra emphasis is needed.

Author's context: If the writer can assume their opinion is trusted then 'a significant 100 million' expresses that opinion.

No context: Explain the ratio, fraction or proportion (Rule: don't assume reader's maths ability')

BTW: Glad that you're taking care expressing statistics!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does 'significant' mean the number is big? You mentioned "the number's significance". It sounds like the number is important rather than big so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase using the adjective *significantly*:

> Significantly, 15% of people said they trust none of these sectors with their data.

> Significantly, 100 million people said they trust none of these sectors with their data.

What it actually means is *The (unnamed) speaker considers it significant that ...* which is the same idea expressed in the original quote.